# is there anyway to restrict a method in module from import in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I have a python directory like below.. in test.py i have a,b,c methods.

While import test i dont want user to import c method. One way is making as c method as private. Is there anyway to achieve that in `__init__.py` or using `__import__`

```
    test
     __init__.py
     test.py
```

I have see few solution in stackoverflow am not getting a way to achieve that.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the issue with importing `c`?  You could select what you do want to import, but if you have more than 3 methods that gets a bit tedious.

Comment: i have some code which i want to hide.

Comment: There is no such thing as private methods in Python, and if someone is able to import your module, they can also open up the python file which will mean they have access to the code anyway.  Just take the code out of the module that you don't want to share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for absolute private methods, then python is the wrong language for you - go to Java or C/++/# or some other language that supports the distinction between `public` and `private`. In python, if it is known something exists, then it is generally possible to access that thing no matter how hidden it is.

If you're simply trying to limit the *convenient options* of the user when they import your module, then you can simply selectively include or exclude methods in `__init__.py`. Say that you have

> `test.py`

```
def a():
    pass
def b():
    pass
def c():
    pass
```

and you wanted `a` and `b` to be accessible to the user but `c` not to be, then you could do

> `__init__.py`

```
from .test import a, b
```

and export the folder as a module. Now, when a user does

```
import test
```

they get access to *only* the stuff that's in the namespace by the end of `__init__.py` (that is, they can get `test.a` and `test.b`, but `test.c` doesn't exist). Since you never included `c` in `__init__.py`, it doesn't appear there.

Note that `c` would still be accessible by doing

```
from test.test import c
```

which accesses the sourcefile directly.

---

Alternatively, you can designate on a *per-file basis* which names should be immediately accessible by using a built-in variable `__all__`. The following will have the same effect as the above code:

> `test.py`

```
...
__all__ = ['a', 'b']  # note that 'c' is excluded
```

> `__init__.py`

```
from test.py import *  # imports a and b, but not c
```

Comment: Note: In C# and Java, the reflection facilities generally allow you to access anything, including `private` stuff, it's just inconvenient. It's not a security feature, it's to reduce the scope of the public API, but it's all there. Python differs in making the decision that privacy is a convention, and making it hard to work around when you might have a real need to bypass the public API is infantilizing programmers. In C++, you have raw memory access, so just about anything is accessible (unless the optimizer optimized it out of existence).

Comment: Thanks for your time. But using __all__ also we can access it directly but putting it in __init__ much better